# How is dead device identification done in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, push-notification, mpns

How is dead device identification done in windows phone when we make use of micosoft push notification service? Does mspn store information about such devices? Is it possible for an application to retrieve the list?

Comment: i have a web service that send notification to devices that has installed an app say 'X'. However if the device was inactive for a long period (say not in use), there is no need for me to pass message to msp service. So is there a way to identify such inactive devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uri Channels can expire. This is why you should regularly check and refresh them from the client.

If the channel is no longer valid (as will happen when the app isn't used for a long time and the URI expires) you'll get an error in the repsonse when you try and send the message.
You shoudl use this method to detect URIs that are no longer valid.

There is no way to get a list of URIs that are no longer valid or to test validity without sending a message.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ask the server for any expired notification channels however if you look t the response codes coming back from the MS services when you're attempting to send a notification (from your server) you'll be able to determine if the channel has expired. If you look at [Push Notification Service Response Codes for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941100%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) you'll note that basically if you get a `404 Not Found` back from the service then the channel has been expired and you should stop sending to it. It's worthwhile handling the other cases as well. Eg. Handling `200 OK` / `QueueFull` messages correctly allows you to lighten the workload on your server by pausing notifications for that subscription for a period of time.